# Find index of an array element in an array in numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Suppose I have a 2d array like this:

```
a= array([[151,  24],
       [152,  24],
       [153,  24],
       ...,)
```

a[0] would return `array([151,  24])`. But if I want to return the index of the array element `[151,  24]`, neither `np.where` nor `np.isin` work (they both return a list of True/False). I have also tried .any() and .all() without any success.

Is there an elegant way to find the index of an array element in a 2d array?

```
np.isin(a, [151,  24])
>> array([[ True,  True],
       [False,  True],
       [False,  True],
       ...,
       [False, False],
       [False, False],
       [False, False]])

np.where(a == [151,  24])
>> (array([    0,     0,     1,     2,     5,    14,    28,    66,   108,
          149,   184,   213,   239,   259,   269,   280,   291,   305,
          320,  2737,  2779,  2823,  2880,  2935,  2999,  3075,  4295,
         4365,  4442,  4530,  4621,  4713,  4809,  4901,  4994,  5269,
         6140,  6265,  6394,  6918,  7060,  7203,  7348,  7492,  7632,
         7770,  7917,  8068,  8219,  8372,  8687,  8847,  9009,  9179,
         9348,  9671,  9831,  9999, 10169, 10344, 10523, 13261, 13432,
        13743, 13892, 14042, 14198, 14364, 14533, 14702, 14870, 15035,
        15199, 15361, 15523, 15685, 15849, 16010, 16169, 16325, 16481,
        16638, 16791, 16948, 17100, 17250, 17399, 17544, 17684, 17819,
        17951, 18085, 18213, 18337, 18450, 18557, 18664, 18770, 18874,
        18978, 19085, 19194, 19301, 19410, 19518, 19619, 19714, 19806,
        19897, 19988, 20078, 20162, 20242, 20321, 20396, 20467, 20541,
        20617, 20690, 20756, 20817, 20883, 20945, 21002, 21063],
       dtype=int64),
 array([0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], dtype=int64))
```

Comment: `np.argwhere(np.all(a == [151, 24], axis=1))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[151,  24],
       [152,  24],
       [153,  24]])

b = [151,  24]

print(np.where((np.isin(a,b)).all(axis=1)))
```

Output:

```
(array([0]),)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`numpy.argwhere`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argwhere.html). This acts like `where`, but returns the indicies found instead of the elements